# Laravel route The page isn't redirecting properly

Tags: redirect, laravel, laravel-routing

Trying to route my Laravel Basic Controller I get

```
**The page isn't redirecting properly**
```

and I try to find what I'm doing actually wrong but can't figure out

**Basic Controller**

```
abstract class BaseAdminController extends Controller {

    protected $whitelist = array();

    /**
     * The URL segment that can be used to access the system
     * @var string
     */
    protected $urlAdminSegment;

    /**
     * Initializer.
     *
     * @access public
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct() {

        //Check CSRF token on POST
        $this->beforeFilter('ReportsAdmin\csrf', array('on' => array('post', 'put', 'delete')));

        // Set up Auth Filters
        $this->beforeFilter('ReportsAdmin\auth');
        $this->beforeFilter('ReportsAdmin\inGroup:Admins', array('only' => array('show', 'index', 'create', 'add', 'destroy', 'suspend', 'unsuspend', 'ban', 'unban', 'edit', 'update')));
        // Achieve that segment
        $this->urlAdminSegment = Config::get('reports::app.access_url_admin');

        // Setup composed views and the variables that they require
        //array('except' => array('create', 'store', 'activate', 'resend', 'forgot', 'reset')));
        $composed_views = array('reports::admin*');
        View::composer($composed_views, 'Td\Reports\Composers\AdminPage');
    }
}
```

**filter**

```
   Route::filter('ReportsAdmin\auth', function() {

    if (!Sentry::check())
        return Redirect::guest('admin/login');
});
```

**routes**

```
Route::get( 'admin/login' , array('as' => 'Reports\login',  'uses' => 'Td\Reports\Controllers\Backend\SessionController@create'));
        return Redirect::guest('admin/login');
});
```

Comment: I would say it is the Redirect::guest() to the Redirect::guest(). In the route `admin/login` make a login View instead of that redirect.

Comment: If you are going to redirect to the same URL I would suggest to use `Redirect::back();`